# Retrofit call is not invoking when i call from Android app with multiple activities

Tags: android, retrofit2

I am newbee in Android and Retrofit.

I have an issue invoking `enque` method when i have android with more than one activity.

In one example, i have a single activity and below code works fine. I am able to get required strings.

```
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;

import java.util.List;

import androidpractice.udayrepo.com.androidpractice.retrofit.APIClass;
import retrofit2.Call;
import retrofit2.Callback;
import retrofit2.Response;
import retrofit2.Retrofit;
import retrofit2.converter.gson.GsonConverterFactory;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Log.d("Main","I am  inside the Main");

        Retrofit retorfit=new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(APIClass.BASE_URL)
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .build();

        APIClass api=retorfit.create(APIClass.class);

        Call<List<String>> call=api.getClassSubjectMapping();


        call.enqueue(new Callback<List<String>>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<List<String>> call, Response<List<String>> response) {

                Log.d("Method","I am  inside the method");
                List<String> subjects=response.body();
                for(String str:subjects)
                    Log.d("Subject name : ",str);
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<List<String>> call, Throwable t) {
                Log.d("Error",t.getMessage());
            }
        });
    }
}
```

In another example, i have two activities Activity1 and Activity2. When i click on Activity1, i am navigating to Activity2. I copied the same above code. I am able to debug "`Call<List<String>> call=api.getClassSubjectMapping();`" But  when `call.enqueue` is executed, just coming out of that method. While executing that step, it is not even going inside `onResponse` method.

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.util.Log;

import java.util.List;

import classelearn.udayrepo.com.classelearn.api.APIClass;
import retrofit2.Call;
import retrofit2.Callback;
import retrofit2.Response;
import retrofit2.Retrofit;
import retrofit2.converter.gson.GsonConverterFactory;

public class LearningSelector_Activity extends AppCompatActivity {

    protected  void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.learning_selector_layout);

        Retrofit retorfit=new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(APIClass.BASE_URL)
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .build();

        APIClass api=retorfit.create(APIClass.class);

        Call<List<String>> call=api.getClassSubjectMapping();


        call.enqueue(new Callback<List<String>>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<List<String>> call, Response<List<String>> response) {

                Log.d("Method","I am  inside the method");
                List<String> subjects=response.body();
                for(String str:subjects)
                    Log.d("Subject name : ",str);
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<List<String>> call, Throwable t) {
                Log.d("Error",t.getMessage());
            }
        });

    }
}
```

Not sure it is problem with Android, retrofit or Sprint boot.

Can someone please help me where i am going wrong?

Comment: If you are not going into `onResponse`, then you are going to `onFailure`.
Can you tell what is the error?

Comment: Not even going to failure. Directly coming end block of the enque method.

Comment: _"But when call.enqueue is executed, just coming out of that method"_ indeed expected behavior. Retrofit's `enqueue()` method is asynchronous. You need to put break point **inside** `onResponse()` and `onFailure()` methods while debugging. If that's not the case, please [edit] and some more details what do you want to do?

Comment: what are you getting in the Logs ?

Comment: I just found out that, Log.d is not shown while debug, so i felt it is not getting into onFailure block. I closely looked into tomcat logs and observed it is going to onFailure method. Then i looked for error message and i came to know the problem is clearText incorporated in AndroidStudio 28 API. Included in manifest and now it is working fine. Now i see a different problem. Sometimes the enque method is executing and sometimes it is not. What is the problem? What i am missing here?

Comment: I am seeing the same problem again. Now even though i have proper log statements this time, the enque() method is not executing onResponse() or onFailute() methods. Can someone help what is causing the issue? but when i invoke the same endpoint through postman i am getting proper responses. Why it is failing with Retrofit enque() method? The control comes after the enque statement.